# django - displaying a single field from inline formset

Tags: django

I was trying to only display a single field from an inline formset, but the field won't show up:

In the template:

```
{{ formset.phone_number }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over forms in the formset:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.phone_number }}
{% endfor %}
```

See [documentation on formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/):

> The formset gives you the ability to iterate over the forms in the formset and display them as you would with a regular form:

```
>>> formset = ArticleFormSet()
>>> for form in formset:
...     print(form.as_table())
```